# Getting events from external file to fullCalendar in node.js

Tags: node.js, fullcalendar, handlebars.js

I am sorry for the scope of my last question(Simple FullCalendar using node.js and Handlebars [closed]). It turns out that the problem in using fullCalendar in node.js was a small javaScript syntax error. 
Thank you everybody who tried to help.

However, I got a little problem while getting events from external file. I would appreciate the help.

I am trying to send an array of events from index.js. The array contains the key-value pairs as,

```
event_list[event_list_index]={id:event_list_index,title:course_name,start:start_time,end:end_time,dow:DOW};
```

I am sending it to index.hbs view as,

```
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { event_list: event_list});
});
```

Then in my index.hbs I am doing,

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            now: '2016-10-10',
            editable: true, // enable draggable events
            aspectRatio: 1.8,
            scrollTime: '00:00', // undo default 6am scrollTime
            eventOverlap:false,
            slotDuration :'00:15:00',
            header: {
                left: 'title',
                center: 'timelineDay,agendaWeek,listWeek',
                right:'next,prev'
            },
            defaultView: 'timelineDay',
            events:{{event_list}}
        });
```

When I debug this I find that it is taking all of them as Objects like this,

```
events:[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

However, I am not able to convert these into EventObjects. I use fullCalendar for a very few things and do not work much with it. So facing difficulties with it.
Anybody have an idea about how to do it?
Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. I stringify the contents using JSON.stringify as,

```
event_list.stringify = JSON.stringify(event_list);
```

It works!